# How to return all data in a column from ADSI Openquery?

Tags: sql, sql-server, active-directory

I'm trying to get a varbinary datatype from Active Directory openquery (specifically, the 'thumbnailPhoto' attribute), however, it seems to truncate the data returned to 256 characters. I used an Active Directory application to see the data that is currently stored and it is a lot bigger than 256 bits so there is definitely a problem with data truncation.

My query looks like this:

```
SELECT     *
FROM         OPENQUERY(ADSI, 
                      'SELECT thumbnailPhoto
FROM ''LDAP://X.X.X.XXX/OU=XX,OU=XX,dc=XX,dc=XX''  
where objectClass = ''User''')
```

I have tried researching ways of casting/converting within the openquery but it seems to either not be possible and/or never discussed.

Comment: The SQL Server interface to Active Directory is **very limited** (and not being updated anymore) - I'd recommend against using it - use some other way to fetch that data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, it is very difficult to work with the SQL Server interface to AD so what I had to do was use the DirectorySearch .net library along with LDAP querying (http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa996205(v=exchg.65).aspx) to obtain all the information from AD without any data truncation.